# Type hinting with pandas dataframe slices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, type-hinting

I am trying to type-hint some code that uses a lot of pandas DataFrames. I've noticed that if I slice a DataFrame, e.g. with

```py
sliced_df = df[df.x > 0]
```

then the return type is assumed by Pylance to be `Series[unknown]`, even when it's a DataFrame. This is proving annoying, as I obtain errors from Pylance when I try to feed the `sliced_df` into a function that expects a DataFrame. One solution would be to change all of the expected inputs into type `Union[pd.DataFrame, pd.Series]`, but I want to avoid this because the input should never actually be a Series.

Is there a way to cast the sliced DataFrame as a DataFrame, or otherwise help the type hinter figure it out?

Comment: this has been an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/252) for almost 2 years now, without much progress so far

Comment: a very ugly workaround would be `sliced_df = pd.DataFrame(df[df.x > 0])`

Comment: Or `cast` to avoid runtime penalty.